# ezAPI What is the correct format for EzExcelCM ConnectionString

Tags: ezapi

I'm trying to create a EzAPI dataflow with an Excel Source but it keeps giving me a type error which I suspect has to do with the fact that I'm not sure how to create the EzExcelCM connection string.  Does anyone have a sample?

I tried using the path and name of the source excel file but that didn't work.

Comment: A type error?  As in data type?  It might be due to a datatype being the wrong type, such as an instance where we assume a value is 304 but instead the value is "304" with quotes, and so its a string instead of a number, and thus if you throw it into a math formula, it will complain about the logic falacy of adding words together instead of numbers.

Comment: I don't think so.  I comment out the connectionstring and it still gave me errors.  I'm wondering if the EzExcelCM just has issues.  I wish I had a working sample from someone.

Comment: I see, it sounds like its more of an issue with the format of the connection string, alas I can't help you there.